# C++ .exe stopped working

Tags: c++

I am having a very difficult time with c++.
I made a hello world that has compiled to make YouTube.exe and main.o.
I run the program and it prints hello world, but then says YouTube.exe has stopped working.
Even when I move main.o to a different directory, YouTube.exe still prints hello world and stops working!
So I have 2 questions:
1. Why did the program still print hello world when main.o was removed?
2. Why did the program stop working? This was the code:

```
main.cpp:

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a;
    cout << "Hello World!";
    cin >> a; //to make the program pause

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use cin.get() to pause the program as well; it looks a bit cleaner than cin >> a;.

Answer (score 2):

Because the .o file is the [object file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) which contains your program but it is still to be linked and relocated to a real executable binary.

This means that `YouTube.exe` already contains what's inside `main.o`, but in an executable format.

What actually happens is that the compiler produces the **.o** files (every object file compiled by itself), then the linker links all **.o** files together, resolve any dependancy and relocate what is needed to produce the real **.exe** file.

Comment: The code is correct according to what you posted, which compiler are you using?

Comment: mingw compiler. I didn't know it could compile differently.

Comment: I think because my system is 64bit and the compiler is 32bit?